# npm can't be installed at all with Node.js 18

Tags: node.js, npm

I have not used JavaScript in my system at all. I'm planning to use TypeScript. However, `npm`, and `yarn` don't work at all.

I removed Node.js 14. Then, I installed Node.js 18. I tried eliminating `npm` and `npm-cache` folders.

Node.js is correctly installed. However, `npm` installation is not working.

`npm -v` command output:

[image: npm -v command output]

---

Win10 was Updated to Win11.  Then, npm could not be installed.
The reason has not been found.
All new data, applications, etc. were stored on an HDD.
Then, win11 was reinstalled. The most recent NPM was installed.  Then, I checked npm also was installed.
The reason has not been found.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below command and make sure that the `node_modules` folder is properly created with all dependencies.
If the `node_modules` folder already exists, try the below command after deleting the existing `node_modules` folder.

```
npm install
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply.  I tried it.  But, nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

Please re-run your NodeJS setup file and then try after this [option selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOQ3J.png). It's will reinstall the npm in your system. hope it should work for you.